# gradle javaCompile.doLast don't work

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio, gradle

I meet a error, in my gradle file , "javaCompile.doLast" doesn't work,
this is my gradle file

```
import org.aspectj.bridge.IMessage
import org.aspectj.bridge.MessageHandler
import org.aspectj.tools.ajc.Main

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.aspectj:aspectjtools:1.8.5'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles 'proguard.cfg'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds true
        abortOnError true
    }
}

final def log = project.logger
final def variants = project.android.applicationVariants

variants.all { variant ->
    println "AAAAAAAA";

    JavaCompile javaCompile = variant.javaCompile
    javaCompile.doLast {
        println "CCCC"
        String[] args = ["-showWeaveInfo",
                         "-1.5",
                         "-inpath", javaCompile.destinationDir.toString(),
                         "-aspectpath", javaCompile.classpath.asPath,
                         "-d", javaCompile.destinationDir.toString(),
                         "-classpath", javaCompile.classpath.asPath,
                         "-bootclasspath",  project.android.bootClasspath.join(File.pathSeparator)]
        log.debug "ajc args: " + Arrays.toString(args)
        println "BBBBBBB";

        println javaCompile.destinationDir.toString()
        println javaCompile.classpath.asPath

        MessageHandler handler = new MessageHandler(true);
        new Main().run(args, handler);
        for (IMessage message : handler.getMessages(null, true)) {
            switch (message.getKind()) {
                case IMessage.ABORT:
                case IMessage.ERROR:
                case IMessage.FAIL:
                    log.error message.message, message.thrown
                    break;
                case IMessage.WARNING:
                    log.warn message.message, message.thrown
                    break;
                case IMessage.INFO:
                    log.info message.message, message.thrown
                    break;
                case IMessage.DEBUG:
                    log.debug message.message, message.thrown
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

When i run gradle info ,
I can see  "AAA" print twice,but "BBB" and "CCC" doesn't print,
I don't know what's wrong in the gradle file,
I copy the "variants" from https://github.com/android10/Android-AOPExample

＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝update＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝

sorry！ this is my fault , 
If  run "gradle clean build " in commandline ,it  works, and work fine when I press run button in Intellij,

but if I haven't run the command ,this can't work  if I press run button in Intellij,

So a new question, Different between the "commandline" and "Intellij run button" ,

Comment: The `doLast` action you added to the task `javaCompile` is only executed if you actually execute the specific Java compilation task. You are executing the task `info` but not `javaCompile`.